# Copying array while excluding element(s)

Tags: arrays, d

Is there a standard way to copy an array excluding elements equal to an object? My current naive solution:

```
T[] without(T)(T[] array, T what){
    T[] a;
    foreach(element; array)
        if(element != what)
            a ~= element;
    return a;
}
```

Removing elements from an array seems unnecessarily difficult in D and the immutable approach seems pretty nice, so I'd like to create a new one instead of modifying the existing array.
`std.array.replace` would work well, but it does not accept `[]` as second argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want `std.algorithm`'s [filter](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#.filter).

For example:

```
import std.algorithm, std.array;
void main() {
  auto a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4];
  auto without3 = a.filter!(x => x != 3).array;
  assert(without3 == [1, 2, 4]);
}
```

note that filter returns a `FilterResult` (a type of range), not an `array`. The call `.array` at the end (from `std.array`) converts the `FilterResult` into an `array`.
You should call `.array` if you want to create and store a separate 'copy'. If you just want to iterate over the `FilterResult`, you can use `foreach` like you would with any range.